# Is it possible to have autocomplete in a notebook in Google Colab?

Tags: autocomplete, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

By autocomplete I mean having something like Intellisense in VS Code by which I can see available functions or members in a particular library?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yup. Press control space (or command space, on a Mac) and autocomplete suggestions will appear.

[image]

Comment: command + space will change my keyboard language on my Mac. I need to use TAB instead.

Comment: How can we have the same level in our local jupyter notebook?

Comment: @Shashwat if you found the way can you share, please.

Comment: ctrl + space on mac as well.

Comment: Command + space open Spotlight search. Ctrl + space doesn't work too. Option + Esc worked for me.

Comment: Same as @HarshitGangwar . Option + Esc worked for me. Command + space open Spotlight search and  Ctrl + space will change my keyboard language

Answer (score 35):

If you navigate to `Settings...` and then uncheck "Automatically trigger code completions":

[image]
[image]

...you'll then be able to use tab-to-complete like in a conventional Jupyter notebook. From the Keyboard Shortcuts page of the Colaboratory app:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm for me! It sure would be nice if tha Goog respected upstream defaults.

Comment: Finally! Something that is similar to a normal jupyter notebook

Answer (score 9):

I'm on a macbook pro, <kbd>Option</kbd>+ <kbd>Esc</kbd> performs autocomplete for me.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (works on Mac as well), but I have to run the cell once:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one language on your macbook then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for Mac, as well as for Windows.
Works like magic, see the image below:

[image]

If you have more than one language you are switching between languages using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, you need to use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it work the same way as with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Not sure about Mac, however.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for what keyboard shortcut works for you in the settings in the keyboard shortcuts inside of the tools tab.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the block has been ran once for this to work.

control + space

Then drop down selection will appear.