# How to add autocomplete feature in google colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ide, google-colaboratory

I recently started using Google Colab and absolutely love to use it. But i want to start autocomplete feature(Hinterland) in Google colab.
How to add hinterland or auto autocomplete in google colab?

Comment: Have you tried to press Ctrl + Space or Tab ?

Comment: Also try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043420/9454010